# Why would a Samsung 960 PRO 512GB show up as a 250GB drive on my machine?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, pci-express, nvme

I have an older motherboard, an ASUS P87ZZ-Pro with Thunderbolt. I recently purchased a [VanTec M.2 NVMe + M.2 SATA SSD PCIe X4 Adapter](http://www.vantecusa.com/products_detail.php?p_id=207&p_name=M.2%20NVMe%20%2B%20M.2%20SATA%20SSD%20PCIe%20x4%20Adapter&pc_id=14&pc_name=Serial%20ATA&pt_id=4&pt_name=Add-on%20Cards) PCI-E NVME adapter card and installed a Samsung 960 PRO 512GB NVME into the adapter.

Windows 10 boots normally, not from the NVME. However, it detects the 960 PRO as being 250GB instead of 512GB. The performance of the drive is quite good.

Why would it be only showing half the actual size of the NVMe?

[image]

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of the Disk Management window.

Comment: I would but I'm at work. It shows up as a drive with a 234GB capacity. I can format it and it works. In the device manager it's being shown as a Samsung PRO 250GB.

Comment: We can't help without that screenshot.  I am going to guess the adapter is to blame.

Comment: Could be. I'm just saying what the screenshot shows. It shows a drive with less than 512GB capacity. It can be formatted etc. Thank you. The adapter is a cheap VanTec.

Comment: "The adapter is a cheap VanTec" - This isn't enough to even find the specifications on the adapter.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The PCIe adapter has been linked in the question. I believe I've included all relevant details. Thanks again.

Comment: 100% speculation, but there is a 250GB version of the [Samsung 960 Evo](https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-960-EVO-Internal-MZ-V6E250BW/dp/B01LYFKX41) M.2 drive. Perhaps Windows is confusing the two?

Comment: Doubt it.  I suspect the problem is entirely the adapter

Comment: Honestly, I think you have the 250 GB version of the drive. If you paid for the 512 GB one, then return it, RMA it, or get rid of it some other way.

Comment: Windows thinks it's a 960 EVO 250GB using two different adapters. I'm going to return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the NVMe drive. I bought another one and it is being reported by Windows as a Samsung 960 PRO 512GB while the faulty one was being reported as a 960 EVO 250GB.

Comment: Less of a faulty drive, unless the wrong firmware was applied to it, suspect the vendor might be at fault. Was this drive new?

Comment: Yes the drive was new in the box bought from Fry's. The one that "worked" I bought from Amazon.

Comment: I suspect this may be a case of fraud through swapping labels. Either on the part of someone in the supply chain, or on the part of a customer who bought and returned the drive.